# Page is postback after click handling for the chart

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, clientscript

I created a `Protected PostBackString As String` on the top of my VB.NET page. And then i called `<%=PostBackString %>` from my javacript which is shown below.

```
$.ajax({
                             type: "POST",
                             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                             url: "ComponentFailureChart.aspx/BindEmployees",
                             data: data,
                             dataType: "json",
                             success: function (result) {


                                  <%=PostBackString %>
                             alert("Success");
                               }
```

After that, I am using the below code to call a method after PostBackString called from javascript.

```
PostBackString = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(Me, "MyEventArgumentName")

    If Request("__EVENTARGUMENT") = "MyEventArgumentName" Then
        BindGridview()
    End If
```

It works fine now, but my problem is it creating a postback. Is there any way to run this code without a postback?

Can I use any alternative way rather than use `Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference` to prevent this?

Pls help me.

Comment: It looks to me, you might be using a submit button which is causing the postback. Do you have a button you are clicking on the web form which is firing that ajax call?

Comment: No. I did not use button. Actually i am using a linked chart. When the user click the bar of the chart, then it will bind the gridview based on their selection.

Comment: Could you update your question to include the click handling for the chart?

Comment: @Malcor, updated. Do you have any suggestion?